# How do I get useEffect to run on array sort?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object like this

```
const example = [{medicineName : "Some name"
    medicineId : 1}
    {medicineName : "Some other name"
    medicineId : 2}
]


const [filteredMedicineList, setFilteredMedicineList] = useState([]);
```

I map over `filteredMedicineList` to produce some other DOM elements.

```
filteredMedicineList.map((data) => {
    return <SingleMedicine data={data} key={data.medicineId} />;
})
```

Also on the page, I have some sort of `button` that when clicked is supposed to sort the `medicineList` in a particular order.

```
const compareFunction = (a, b) => {
    if (a.medicineName < b.medicineName) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (a.medicineName > b.medicineName) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
};

const handleSort = (sortBy) => {
    filteredMedicineList.sort(compareFunction);
    console.log("After sort");
    console.log(arrayX);
};
```

**My question** is **how do I get the sorted changes or results to reflect on the components that I mapped over**. I cant use `useEffect` because I believe `useEffect` is when something changes and I am not sure anything here changes. Like in my example I want when the array is ordered in the order in which the `<Singlemedicine/>` component is shown to also change.

**Second Question**. In my `compareFunction()` that's just some code, I copy-pasted, I did not understand it. How is the equality checked in strings?  Like how does `javascript` determine that String "COW" is greater than "Carmel" is it by the length of the strings? Forgive a noob and then help

Comment: Your `compareFunction()` method no way returns `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line changes the `filteredMedicineList` directly and still React sees the old reference to the array which does not make trigger the React rerendering.

```
filteredMedicineList.sort(compareFunction);
```

You need to use `setFilteredMedicineList` to make changes to it like below. This creates a new array reference with sorted items in a new array which triggers the rerendering.

```
setFilteredMedicineList((prevFilteredMedicineList) => {
  const copyOfprevFilteredMedicineList = [...prevFilteredMedicineList];
  copyOfprevFilteredMedicineList.sort(compareFunction);
  return copyOfprevFilteredMedicineList;
});
```

Another issue is your compare function return `-1` in the first two conditions it should also be corrected.

```js
const example = [
  { medicineName: "Some name", medicineId: 1 },
  { medicineName: "Some other name", medicineId: 2 }
];

const App = () => {
  const [filteredMedicineList, setFilteredMedicineList] = React.useState(example);

  const compareFunction = (a, b) => {
    if (a.medicineName < b.medicineName) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a.medicineName > b.medicineName) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  };

  const handleSort = (sortBy) => {
    setFilteredMedicineList((prevFilteredMedicineList) => {
      const copyOfprevFilteredMedicineList = [...prevFilteredMedicineList];
      copyOfprevFilteredMedicineList.sort(compareFunction);
      return copyOfprevFilteredMedicineList;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleSort}>SORT</button>

      {filteredMedicineList.map(({ medicineName, medicineId }) => (
        <div key={medicineId}>{medicineName}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: I totally understand. So I must use setState otherwise react will not rerender my component. Thanks a lot  @Amilasenadheera

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `setState` to trigger a render. The array's reference should change and the component will rerender.

```
const handleSort = (sortBy) => {
    filteredMedicineList.sort(compareFunction);
    setFilteredMedicineList([...filteredMedicineList]);
    console.log("After sort");
    console.log(arrayX);
  };
```

Regarding your second question, how cow is larger than camel is by comparing character one by one. C then O > C then A.